# Numerically stable reverse automatic differentiation of power(x, y)?

Tags: computer-algebra

I would like to compute the adjoints $\bar x$ and $\bar y$, from a reverse automatic differentiation perspective, of the expression $x^y$. The adjoint $\bar{x^y}$ is already known; and we can assume $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 1$.

The "easy" solution consists of rewriting the expression $x^y=e^{y \ln x}$, and proceed piece-wise from there. However, this solution proves to be unstable numerically, it gives:

$$\bar y = \bar{x^y} x^y \ln x$$

and

$$\bar x = \bar{x^y} x^{y-1} y$$

Is there any way to rewrite and/or approximate those expressions with something that is not going to numerically diverge when $x \approx 0$?